# only show a small part of the map in C# code by GMAP and OSM

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, openstreetmap, gmap.net

I would like to show a map by Open Street Map.

I have a C# code in VS2013 to show a map by GMAP and OSM.

The map can only show a small part of the map. I think I can see a region map for the specified lat/long.

Why ?

Thanks

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;

namespace drawMapByGmap
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     GMapOverlay overlayOne;
     String contry;
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); 

     }

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mapexplr_Load(sender, e);
    }

    private void mapexplr_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //initialisation de notre map
        gMapControl1.SetPositionByKeywords("Tunisia");
        gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        gMapControl1.MinZoom = 3;
        gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 17;
        gMapControl1.Zoom = 5;
        gMapControl1.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
        //ajout des overlay
        overlayOne = new GMapOverlay("OverlayOne");
        //ajout de Markers
        overlayOne.Markers.Add(new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(36.657403, 10.327148), GMarkerGoogleType.blue));
        ////ajout de overlay à la map
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(overlayOne);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, are you maybe disconnected from the internet? You're using `AccessMode.ServerAndCache`, so the part you see might be from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and nothing wrong with it, so you can try setting the Manager Mode to Server only

```
GMapControl1.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly
```

And make sure you are connected to the internet, here is an image for my test

[image]